# Why my computer won't enter sleep mode?

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

My Windows 8.1 set sleep time and turn off display to 1 minute
[image]

Network adapter wake the computer disabled.
[image]

`powercfg` command seems to have no problem.
[image]

Even `powercfg -energy` still found nothing prevent the system from automatically entering sleep. All of the error said:

> Note that this issue will not prevent the system from sleeping.

[image]

I have no more idea how to check what is preventing my computer from sleeping. It used to work few days ago.

Comment: Can you manually send the computer to sleep?

Comment: @Jack Yes, I can.